# How to detect SQL Server stored procedure failure from JDBC client?

Tags: jdbc

I have some Java code that uses JDBC to execute a "CREATE PROCEDURE" statement on a SQL Server 2008 instance. The create proc is failing due to an error ("Implicit conversion from data type xml to varchar(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query.").

This error is *not* being raised to the JDBC client and so I have no indication that the sproc creation failed. As far as the JDBC statement and connection are concerned, after executing the CREATE PROC statement, there were no problems.

So does anyone know how to detect this problem from the JDBC client?

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

I discovered that using PreparedStatement rather than Statement gets sproc compilation warnings raised as SQLExceptions.